# Postfix disable mail sending for specific local account

Tags: debian, postfix, email-server

how can I disable mail sending for specific mail account at my postfix mail server?

in my main.cf I have:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
reject_unauth_pipelining,
reject_non_fqdn_sender,
reject_unknown_sender_domain,
reject_unlisted_sender,
check_sender_access cidr:/etc/postfix/mx_access.cidr,
permit
```

Something like:

```
check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access

/etc/postfix/sender_access:email@domain.com REJECT

postmap hash:sender_access

service postfix reload
```

Can help with my problem or I am doing it wrong?

I just need to block sending opportunity for few accounts only receiving allowed.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent someuser from sending mail via postfix, in /etc/postfix/main.cf, you just need to specify that within the authorized_submit_users setting like so:

authorized_submit_users = !someuser, static:all

Comment: Is this solution working for mailboxes? or only for system users?